# How can I draw two text side by side with two different size in Android?

Tags: android

I would like to draw a number + a percentage sign (%) side by side and I would like the have a small size on the percentage like the image I attach.

[image]

Here is my code and I can't figure out the position of the % in the last line of the code. Since the number can go from 0 to 100, so the position that I adjust is very ugly as the % sign doesn't align with the number properly.

```
p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
p.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
p.setTextSize(width/2.5f);
canvas.drawText(pctText, width/2 , height/2, p);
canvas.drawText("%", width/2 , height/2, p);
```

I am wondering if there is a solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you set it in your XML, and then set the number textfield relative to the % textfield (using a relative layout)? then it should align properly (ideally)

Comment: I am drawing it on a WallpaperService so I don't have a layout xml.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, `Paint.measureText(String txt)` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, measureText works. Thanks.

Comment: @Kintarō Can you please share the code for the same? Thanks in advance.